# How to add 1 to Variable with Button Click?

Tags: objective-c

I want to add 1 to my variable each time the button is clicked, but instead a 10 digit number appears.  What am I doing wrong with the code below?

```
-(IBAction)recordData:(id)sender {
int randomNumber;
randomNumber = randomNumber + 1;
NSString *myRandomNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", randomNumber];
NSString *CompleteData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:DataView.text];
CompleteData = [CompleteData stringByAppendingString: @"\n"];
CompleteData = [CompleteData stringByAppendingString:myRandomNumber];
DataView.text = CompleteData;
}
```

Comment: `static int randomNumber = 0;` instead of `int randomNumber;`

Answer (score 1):

Make

```
int randomNumber
```

either static or declare it as an instance variable.

What you are currently doing is creating a new varialbe each time when recordData is invoked. Plus you do not initialize it. Local variables are not initialized. Instance variables are initialized with 0/nil. As a result your variable has some random content (as its name suggests anyway :). To that random value you add 1.

Comment: And please don't name the variable "randomNumber" when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your variable is not initialised: `int randomNumber = 0` would fix that.
2. `randomNumber`'s scope is the `recordData:` method. You could make it a static variable a suggested by holex, or even better, make it a property of your class.

Have a look at [Encapsulating Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) in Apple's Objecitve-c Documentation  to learn more about iVars and properties.

Comment: An iVar would do. It does not need to be a property.

Comment: Yes, an iVar would do. But to quote the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html): _It’s best practice to use a property on an object any time you need to keep track of a value or another object._